# SQL Server Distributed Availability Group databases not syncing after a server reboot

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, upgrade, sql-server-2017, distributed-availability-groups

We're getting ready to perform [a large upgrade](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307744/164200) on our SQL Servers and are noticing some unusual behavior with Distributed Availability Groups that I'm trying to resolve before moving forward.

Last month, I upgraded a remote secondary server from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2017. This server is a part of multiple [Distributed Availability Groups (DAGs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups) and a separate [Availability Group (AG)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server). When we upgraded this server, we were unaware that it would get into an [unreadable state](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/963443600997736449), so during the past month we've solely been relying on the primary server.

As a part of the upcoming upgrade, I applied the [CU 4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056498/cumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2017) patch to the server and rebooted it. When the server came back online, the just-patched secondary showed all of the DAGs/AGs were syncing without any issues.

However, the primary was showing a very different story. It was reporting that

- the separate AG was syncing without any issues
- but the DAGs were in a **Not Synchronzing / Not Healthy** state

After initially panicking, I attempted the following things to get things synchronizing again in the DAGs:

- From the primary, I stopped and resumed the data movement. This did not start syncing the data.
- On the secondary (the one I just patched) I ran `ALTER DATABASE [<database] SET HADR RESUME;` - which execute without errors, but did not resume any syncing

My last attempt at syncing the data again was to login to the secondary, and manually restart the SQL Server service. Manually restarting the service seems a bit extreme, as I'd expect the server being rebooted would have been enough.

Has anyone run into this issue where a DAG doesn't start syncing to a secondary after a reboot? If so, how was it resolved?

I checked both the SQL Server error log, and the event viewer on the secondary server, there was nothing out of the ordinary that I could see.

Comment: I've never used SQL 2017 in production, but does it support AG between lower levels of SQL? Every other version you can set up AlwaysOn between different versions, but once you reboot your primary and it fails over to a higher version of SQL it will stop the sync process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please note, this is not a definitive answer but it's the best answer after chatting with [Taryn](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/9003/taryn).

> However, the primary was showing a very different story. It was reporting that the separate AG was syncing without any issues but the DAGs were in a Not Synchronzing / Not Healthy state

If the individual databases and AGs underlying the distributed ag say they healthy and synchronizing, there is a good chance this is just a hiccup in the DMVs and/or SSMS dashboards. Since there was nothing in the errorlog to suggest the replica didn't connect or was in a disconnected state.

Unfortunately since the issue has resolved, it's hard to say exactly what it was... but in the future if this occurs for someone:

- Check [sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-database-replica-states-transact-sql) on all clusters looking for anything that isn't healthy. If all shows healthy, it's possible the DMV hasn't updated yet
- If it's unhealthy check the errorlog/DMVs for connectivity issues (such as not being able to connect to the forwarder/global primary)
- [Dan's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/125593/dan) answer mentions issues that could arise from database startup - though in this case the instance can't be read so that most likely wasn't an issue but could be in your case
- If the database is readable, smoke test with a dummy table/insert or ...
- Extended event session using the DEBUG channel items `sqlserver.hadr_dump_log_block` or `sqlserver.hadr_apply_log_block` to see if the secondary is actually receiving/applying the log blocks or ...
- Perfmon object `SQLServer:Database Replica\Log Bytes Received/sec`

If you're receiving data on that secondary but the distributed ag still shows not synchronizing or not healthy then I'd let it go for a bit to see if the DMV values change since it's obviously receiving and processing log blocks.

If, however, it isn't then we'll need to investigate further which is out of scope of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'll preface this all with the caveat that I do not have any DAGs in production. Fundamentally though this advice should apply between both AGs and DAGs.

Did the synchronization resume following the service restart? If so then my best guess to the cause would be blocking on the redo SPID. If it's still not synchronizing even after the restart, here's what I'd be checking first:

**Blocking of AG redo SPID**

Generally only going to occur on a readable secondary. To check, run the following:

```
select session_id, blocking_session_id, db_name(database_id), wait_type
from sys.dm_exec_requests
where command = 'DB STARTUP'
```

If any blocking SPIDs appear, you'll need to kill them before the secondary can resume (the `DB STARTUP` SPID is what handles the redo operations). I'd suggest reviewing the blocking SPID beforehand to try and determine the cause (usually a long running report).

If you want further information on this, there's a great article (including monitoring for this type of behaviour using XEs) [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2015/01/06/troubleshooting-redo-queue-build-up-data-latency-issues-on-alwayson-readable-secondary-replicas-using-the-wait_info-extended-event/).

**Check DMVs**

If data movement is suspended, you can refer to DMVs to get more information on the suspend reason. Run the following:

```
select db_name(database_id), synchronization_state_desc, database_state_desc, suspend_reason_desc
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states
```

The [BOL article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-database-replica-states-transact-sql) describes the suspend_reason a little further.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Distributed Availability Group (DAG) split between different regions? If so you could be suffering from the default SESSION_TIMEOUT value (10 seconds) being too low. This means that latency between the two regions is too high to reliably complete syncing.

A normal availability group can have its SESSION_TIMEOUT value increased to make the syncing sessions more stable. I noticed late last year that the SESSION_TIMEOUT parameter of DAG's could not be edited. This meant that DAG's were only viable for low latency scenarios. We logged a ticket with Microsoft and earlier this year a hotfix was released.

[Improvement: Configure SESSION_TIMEOUT value for a Distributed Availability Group replica in SQL Server 2016 and 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4090004/configure-session-timeout-value-for-a-dag-replica-in-sql-server)